# Generator function to enumerate files

Tags: node.js, file-system, promise, typescript, generator

I want to implement a function that enumerates all files in directory. I think the function should

- Return a **Promise**, because underlying `readdir` call is prefered over `readdirSync`.
- Be a **generator function**, because checking `statSync(...).isFile()` might take some time and maybe, I will need only first few files...

**So my attempt**

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

function enumerateFiles(dir: string): Promise<IterableIterator<string>> {
    let result = function* (files: string[]): IterableIterator<string> {
        for (let enty of files) {
            let fullpath = path.join(dir, enty);

            if (fs.statSync(fullpath).isFile())
                yield fullpath;
        }
    };

    return new Promise<IterableIterator<string>>((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(result(files));
        });
    });
}
```

**And usage**

```
for (let file of await enumerateFiles(String.raw`C:\Windows\Web\Screen`))
    console.log(file);

// C:\Windows\Web\Screen\img100.jpg
// C:\Windows\Web\Screen\img101.jpg
// ...
```

What do you think? I'm really not sure about combining Promises with generator functions. Especially in this order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the biggest problem with this function that I see is the mixing of async and sync `fs` APIs. This is confusing to the consumer - if I have to deal with promises, then chances are I will expect you are doing everything asynchronously behind the scenes.

I think this function is a good idea, but it would be better if you took advantage of the [Async iterator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration), which Typescript can transpile.

```ts
import * as fs from 'fs'
import { join } from 'path'
import { promisify } from 'util'

const statPromise = promisify(fs.stat)
const readDirPromise = promisify(fs.readdir)

const isFile = (path: string) => statPromise(path)
  .then(stats => stats.isFile())

export async function * enumerateFiles (path: string): AsyncIterableIterator<string> {
  const files = await readDirPromise(path)
  for (const file of files) {
    if (await isFile(join(path, file)) {
      yield file
    }
  }
}
```

And here's an example of usage:

```ts
// Async function is required.
async function main () {
  for await (const file of enumerateFiles('.')) {
    console.log(file)
  }
}

main()
```

Note that to use async iterators, you need to add `esnext.asynciterable` to the `lib` section of your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in posting this - I was pretty sure I knew the async iterator proposal was the way to do this more cleanly, but didn't have the time to look into it until today.

Comment: Hey, this is really cool solution! Thanks for both, notifying me about this proposal and demonstrating it in my problem. I’m starting using this pattern from now :-). Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (let file of await enumerateFiles(String.raw`C:\Windows\Web\Screen`))
```

The await looks like a leaky abstraction. Could your generator *naturally* behave synchronously?  A quote from [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_generators.html#sec_overview-generators)

> **22.1.5 Use case: receiving asynchronous data**
>
> Generators can receive input from next() via yield. That means that you can wake up a generator whenever new data arrives asynchronously and to the generator it feels like it receives the data synchronously.

---